# POSTSCRIPT: how to change the weight of a font?

Tags: postscript

I have a regular font only and I want to make certain text look bold,
how can I change the weight of the font?

I tried using 
/Arial findfont [12 0 0 10 0 0] makefont setfont
but it makes the font wider not fatter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is 'you can't'. If your font is a multiple master font and has a bold design axis then you could use that. Otherwise there is no way to ge a true bold that will satisfy a typographer.

You can draw the text 4 times at slightly different horizontal and vertical offsets (the corners of a small square), this is a common way to create a 'fake bold' effect for a font family that isn't available as a bold face. Its not truly a bold font though.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this way but I really hoped that there was another way. 
When a font doesn't exist it is replaced by another, How to make sure it is replaced by another bold font?

Comment: There is no guaranteed method. Most RIPs will allow you to specify a generic default font, and specific replacement fonts (eg Arial-Bold for Helvetica-Bold). There is no specified method for doing this so all rips differ.